# How to open the hosting app from an iMessage extension?

Tags: ios, objective-c, imessage-extension

Say I have an iMessage app extension **MyMessageApp**, it's an extension of **MyContainApp**.

**What I Expect**

When I click a message in iMessage, I want to launch MyContainApp and do something with the message in MyContainApp.

**Code in `didSelectMessage`**

`self.extensionContext openURL:url completionHandler:^(BOOL success)`

**Problem**

The result `success` is always `NO`

Can an iMessage app extension open the hosting App or not?

Here is what I found (*didn't help me*)
[Apple staff said "should be fixed in seed 3"](https://forums.developer.apple.com/message/153441#153441)
and
[Apple staff said "This will be fixed in the next release"](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/54267) in Aug 10,2016

Still, I can't launch MyContainApp. Did I miss anything or there is a new policy about iMessage apps?

Comment: It works fine in our extension, what URL are you passing?

Comment: @combinatorial I use URLScheme "zkbrowser://'' to launch my app.and I this works in Safari.

Comment: If you call openURL on the same URL directly from some code inside your container app, does it work (as essentially that is what the extension is doing).

Comment: @combinatorial I add a button in my container app, and use this code: `[UIApplication sharedApplication] openURL:` to open the URLScheme. it works. (in the handler,success return YES)

Answer (score 2):

I was creating the wrong application!

First created that **MyContainApp**

and the wrong way to create **MyMessageApp** is "new->target->Application->iMessageApplication" .

What I should do is "new->target->Application Extension->iMessage Extension"

and the "open host app" code is:

```
NSString *urlScheme = @"zkbrowser://";
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlScheme];

[self.extensionContext openURL:url completionHandler:^(BOOL success) {
    if (success) {
        NSLog(@">>>success");
    }else{
        NSLog(@">>>fail");
    }
}];
```